how to groupby duplicate values but retain other columns in sqlite
I have joined the tables together as follows
SELECT od.EmployeeID, nv.LastName, nv.FirstName, od.OrderDate, od.ShipperID, od.OrderID, prod.ProductName, ord.Quantity  from Orders as od
INNER JOIN Employees as nv
ON od.EmployeeID = nv.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Shippers as ship
ON od.ShipperID = ship.ShipperID
INNER JOIN OrderDetails as ord
ON od.OrderID = ord.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products as prod
on prod.ProductID = ord.ProductID
WHERE od.EmployeeID = '8' and date(od.OrderDate) >= date('1997-01-01') and ship.ShipperID = '2'

Result:

If you use the command "GROUP BY od.OrderID"

But the result I want is that only the "OrderID" column is grouped.
The ProductName column will be displayed in full (separated by commas) as follows:
Chang, Gustafs Knäckebröd, Mozzarella di Giovanni

Use GROUP_CONCAT() and aggregate by the OrderID:
SELECT od.OrderID, GROUP_CONCAT(prod.ProductName) AS products
FROM Orders AS od
INNER JOIN OrderDetails AS ord
    ON od.OrderID = ord.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products AS prod
    ON prod.ProductID = ord.ProductID
GROUP BY od.OrderID;

If you want to keep the same select list, but just rollup the products as a CSV, then use GROUP_CONCAT() in a subquery and join to it:
SELECT od.EmployeeID, nv.LastName, nv.FirstName, od.OrderDate,
       od.ShipperID, od.OrderID, p.products, ord.Quantity
FROM Orders AS od
INNER JOIN Employees as nv
    ON od.EmployeeID = nv.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Shippers as ship
    ON od.ShipperID = ship.ShipperID
INNER JOIN OrderDetails as ord
    ON od.OrderID = ord.OrderID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ProductID, GROUP_CONCAT(ProductName) AS products
    FROM Products
    GROUP BY ProductID
) p
    ON p.ProductID = ord.ProductID
WHERE
    od.EmployeeID = '8' AND
    DATE(od.OrderDate) >= DATE('1997-01-01') AND
    ship.ShipperID = '2';

